# Cardinal arithmetic in inner models

Tags: logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, large-cardinals

I know that regular cardinals get computed weirdly in inner models of determinacy (this comes up in Jackson's analysis of the projective ordinals $\delta^1_n$); this is a question about a specific case of this.

Suppose $V$ contains a proper class of Woodins. Can we still have $\omega_2^{L(\mathbb{R})}=\omega_2$? If so, how high up can we have $\omega_n^{L(\mathbb{R})}=\omega_n$?

Comment: The second question admits an easy answer: no for $n>2$. $\omega_n^{L(\Bbb R)}$ is singular, so it certainly cannot be $\omega_n$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Great! Do you know a citation for that?

Comment: Also, it is of course possible that $\omega_2^{L(\Bbb R)}<\omega_2$, even without the requirement on Woodin cardinals: simply note that the collapse of $\omega_2$ to $\omega_1$ does not add reals, so it does not change $L(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: I should be grading midterms. But let me take a look.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, that one I knew - it's always possible for $L(\mathbb{R})$ to be bad at arithmetic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hehe, being a bad influence is fun!

Comment: Okay. Now it's getting late, and I want to grade this entire pile tonight. So I will turn to my other desk, and ignore all further things for tonight.

Answer (score 7):

The second question admits an easy negative answer: in models of $\sf AD$ every $\omega_n$ is singular for finite $n>2$.

Kleinberg claimed in the following paper that this is due to Martin, but without reference. He also proved it as Corollary 2.2.

> *E. M. Kleinberg*, [**${\rm AD}\vdash $ “the $\aleph _{n}$ are Jonsson cardinals and $\aleph _{\omega }$ is a Rowbottom cardinal”**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0003-4843(77)80002-8), *Ann. Math. Logic* **12** (1977), no. 3, 229--248. [MR 469769](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=469769), [Zbl 0378.02032](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0378.02032).

Comment: I believe you can also find this result in the book *Infinitary Combinatorics and the Axiom of Determinateness*, by Eugene M. Kleinberg, Lecture Notes in Mathematics #612, Springer, 2006 (originally published in 1977).

Comment: Mitchell, I believe that you're correct. Both these are given as references by your mathematical-brother, Arthur Apter in one of his papers. I went with the paper, as it's easier to get those online (legally, anyway).

Comment: Indeed -- that reference is fine. I just thought I would add the other as well.

Comment: After all these years, is it still exciting to see people refer to your advisor's work, or even to your work?

Comment: Yes, of course :) .  It's a little nostalgic too; that book was published while I was still in graduate school (and, as you say, Gene Kleinberg was my advisor).