# Are there any disasters with Projective Determinacy?

Tags: set-theory, axioms, paradoxes

It is well-known that the Axiom of Choice entails a number of counter-intuitive results, Banach-Tarski paradox is only one example. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104028/what-are-disasters-with-axiom-of-determinacy#) MSE question, Martin Sleziak asked about similar undesirable consequences under the Axiom of Determinacy. I found this question very interesting and, for example, an equivalence relation on the real line with strictly more than continuum many equivalence classes really surprised me!

---

I've been wondering whether one can also find some problematic results under the Axiom of Projective Determinacy - the axiom considered to be "true" by some mathematicians. Are there any "disasters" with Projective Determinacy?

Comment: I mean, Banach–Tarski still holds. Just the partition is not projective.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed, haven't thought about this while writing the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say **no**, there are no "projective determinacy disasters" (other than the already-present ZFC disasters, of course). The point is that our ideas about how *every* set should behave don't really refine to ideas about how every *projective* set should behave - the class of projective sets is sufficiently technical that we approach it with a fairly open mind - and so we don't get the same "kick" as we do from full determinacy.

---

In a bit more detail:

Every determinacy disaster has a corresponding projective analogue - e.g. determinacy implies that the Vitali relation $$x\sim y\iff x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$$ has no transversal, and projective determinacy implies that it has no *projective* transversal. However, this analogy robs the disasters of a lot of their strength: our intuition that the Vitali relation should have a transversal doesn't in my opinion extend to an intuition that it should have a *simple* transversal, so this implication of projective determinacy isn't really counterintuitive.

Indeed, in my opinion this robs the disaster of *all* of its nonintuitiveness, and this pattern continues for all the other determinacy disasters (again, in my opinion).

---

The only disaster I can think of here is *consistency implications*: if you believe that ZFC + a measurable cardinal (for example) is likely to be inconsistent, then (once you see the relevant theorem) you also believe that ZFC + projective determinacy is inconsistent. And personally I don't think there is a truly compelling consistency argument at this level; I do think these theories are consistent, but I can easily imagine being wrong. This, of course, is *not* an issue with choice - Godel showed that ZFC is consistent if ZF is.

Comment: Well, a measurable implies lightface PD, if my memory serves me right, and in fact much more than just that. That's *kind of* a plausibility argument from a measurable to "$n$ Woodin cardinals" for any $n$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't really see how - lightface is much weaker than boldface. And even if I granted that, we'd just be reducing to a justification for a measurable. Honestly, I don't even think there's a truly compelling reason for ZF to be consistent - again, I'm just fairly confident that it is.

Comment: I don't know how Platonism work. I don't get that whole "belief that I'm correct". But if you believe Lightface PD, then I don't see why you wouldn't believe PD itself. Yes, that reduces to $0^\#$ or $x^\#$ for every real $x$, if I remember correctly. But if you really think about that, believing those already justifies a measurable. I mean, embeddings, man. Embeddings!!!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your answer, very interesting; I wish to think about this.

Comment: @Asaf Your first comment is off. The consistency strength of lightface $\Delta^1_2$ determinacy is one Woodin cardinal. And one Woodin cardinal does not *imply* this amount of determinacy, you obtain it in an appropriate forcing extension.

Comment: @Andrés: Huh. So what do you get from sharps? (Also as far as plausibility arguments go, this is my way of saying that the consistency strength is similar.)

Comment: @Asaf Sharps give you $\mathbf\Pi^1_1$ determinacy.

Comment: @Andrés: Ah, right. I knew that I got something mixed up there. Thanks!